# Post form in a button

Tags: laravel

In the admin dashboard you can make a post inactive if its active and vice versa. When you click on the button: 'make inactive', you send this form

```
<form method="POST" action="/admin/posts/inactivate/{{$post->id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     @csrf
     @method('PATCH')
     <input type="number" id="active" name="active" value="1" hidden readonly>
     <button type="submit">Make inactive</button>
</form>
```

I dd'd and made sure the correct 'active' value is given but when I click the button to update the value in the database it just does nothing(redirects back to the dashboard with no change). I have this in my controller

```
public function makeInactive(Post $post){
    
    $attribute = request()->validate([
        'active' => 'required',
    ]);
    
    $post->update($attribute);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

I have the same sort code for updating user data and it works just fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: check the `$fillable` property in the post model if contains the `active` column. if it doesn't you have to add it.

Comment: That was the problem! It's not the first time I forgot I'm working with the fillable. I added the column and everything works just fine. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

it works for me :) but I made the "active" column in the database as integer what about yours ?